# Python: cannot import statsmodels.api --> ImportError: cannot import name 'getargspec'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, statsmodels

I am trying to import statsmodels.api to run a logistic regression and i get the following error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'getargspec'

I have tried to updgrde: pip install statsmodels --upgrade

Still nothing.

Comment: can you uninstall it first and then reinstall it?

Comment: Having the same issue, any updates?

Comment: same here , I do not what to do . in terminal , imported without problem .

Answer (score 0):

Use pycharm instead of jupyter notebook, you may get some warning messages, but without this importerror.